# Programmatically create SQL Agent Job running SSIS package in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, smo

I have a SSIS package that is being used to simply transfer data from one database to another on the same server on a SQL Server Agent job. I want to be able to create multiple jobs for different databases at any time so I am trying to create a C# program to create the jobs.

Looking at the [Job Step](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobstep(v=sql.110).aspx) class I cannot find a way to set the type for the step like in the UI:
[image: SQL Server Agent Job Step Type]

I've tried setting the command to the same form that an already existing job has for calling a SSIS package in the SSIS catalog:

```
JobStep jobStep = new JobStep(job, "Transfer");
jobStep.Command = @"/ISSERVER ""\SSISDB\ABC\ABC\Transfer.dtsx"" /SERVER FRISCHE /Par ""DestinationConnectionOLEDB_InitialCatalog"";""Dest_Test"" /Par ""SourceConnectionOLEDB_InitialCatalog"";""Src_Test"" /Par ""$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)"";1 /Par ""$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E";
```

But the step that this creates always defaults to the Transact-SQL script option. Is there some way I can tell the `JobStep` object that I want a type of an SSIS package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [SubSytem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobstep.subsystem(v=sql.110).aspx). The Enum values are [listed here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.agentsubsystem(v=sql.110).aspx)

```
Ssis - Specifies the SQL Server Integration Services subsystem.
```

Specifically, you want `Ssis`. Code should be approximately

```
jobStep.SubSystem = AgentSubSystem.Ssis;
```